# TextArea and sidemenu issue in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I've a couple of `textField`s and `textArea`s in a screen. When any one of them is focused and then if the sidemenu is opened, I can write on top of side menu. The keyboard doesn't disappear when sidemenu is clicked. In other cases as well, when keyboard is opened and the components like Label etc are touched, it'd be nicer if the keyboard disappear automatically.

See the video [here](https://youtu.be/vIzYJo6kb4Y)

Comment: This looks like a regression in the virtual keyboard probably due to this change: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/right-sidemenu-tab-order.html please file an issue

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2444

Comment: I think it is solved in android but in iOS the problem still exists. It doesn't happen all the time in iOS but if you focus on text inputs and keyboard is on, then when you scroll the component below the keyboard and open the sidemenu, the issue appears in iOS. Sometimes the components appear below the keyboard initially & the issue appears with sidemenu. I have tested it in iOS 6 plus

See the video here https://youtu.be/NLtI0TTzWms